# nothing happens after building an OpenCV project

Tags: eclipse, opencv

I'm using OpenCV for the first time (Windows, Eclipse), after installing and configuring Eclipse using this manual:

http://tommy.chheng.com/development/windows_development_setup.html

I tried running the example, but nothing happens after build!

when the program reaches this line:

```
img=cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
```

it just stops.
I tried printing to screen before and after this command, but nothing happens. it does print to screen only when I comment out the entire code (great, ha?...)

I also tried:

```
img=cvLoadImage(argv[1], -1);
```

but still, no good..

Thanks so much for any help.
Chen.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are providing an image file as the first argument, right?

Comment: Try running the program with a valid path to a image file as an argument in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that <...>\OpenCV\bin has been permanently added to the system PATH? It requires a restart of windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using command line arguments with your binary (which is mostly the case when you compile and run your code using and IDE) then try using a fixed path to an image file and see if it works.

Try using the following line with `lena.jpg` in the same folder as your binary output

```
img = cvLoadImage("lena.jpg");
```

if this works fine then there is nothing wrong with your setup, and can be fixed by using proper command line arguments with your binary output

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I just added `<opencvDIR>..\opencv\build\x86\mingw\bin` to the system path and  restart my computer.